# huawei matebook d15 issue with wifi and bluetooth

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

Seems to be like my Matebook D15 is having issues when i turn on the bluetooth adapter meanwhile im using the wifi.

Example: Im on youtube (with the bluetooth adapter off) watching a 1080p video with absolutely no problems.

If i turn on the bluetooth adapter and connect my headphones. The youtube video stars to get stucked loading the video like a slow internet connection.
i adjunt an lshw of my lap.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem when i connect my bluetooth earpiece. is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have that same problem, but it is not consistent. If I reconnect the headphones it is mostly gone. Do you use a docking station or something else too? I have a Dell D6000, which introduced some problems in that area too.
PS: cannot add this as a comment, as reputation is missing. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Did a little research on this one because of having some stuttering issues when I'm connected with any speaker/headset on the Huawei Matebook d15. After troubleshooting, updating, and re-installing the Bluetooth hardware none worked.

What I found out was an online article that **some laptops are using the same frequency for wifi and Bluetooth connection which causes interference**, I did some experimenting on my own, and when the laptop doesn't use the wifi the stuttering is gone..

Some solution that I stumbled upon was changing the wifi bandwidth connection of my router. So I connected my laptop to the 5ghz and tried listening to some music, it helped a little when the wifi traffic is not heavy, but it did not totally eliminate the stuttering. My last hope is to buy a Bluetooth adapter online, hoping it will have a smooth connection. Will comment back again if none worked and if the Bluetooth adapter works smoothly.

*Not an expert in computer hardware, but I hope it gave you some idea, just assuming the research that I did is correct hahah. This issue is a hassle!